# Electrodeposition of Ni

Tags: electrochemistry, liquid-crystals

How can one electrodeposit Nickel on a substrate using a liquid crystal template?

substrate is Indium Tin Oxide coated plate and the template is cetyl trimethylammonium bromide(CTAB)+WATER+ETHANOL

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very specific case. I would say that you should start with a standard Ni electroplating solution and see the result. You could then adjust the parameters of your plating operation and the concentrations of the additives in the solution.

However, I have a bigger concern. How stable is your liquid crystal template under applied potential in an electrolyte? Before trying to deposit Ni, you should try to do simple electrochemistry find the potential window where your template stays intact.